# Variable assignment followed by other variable names

Tags: javascript

In the following code, a is output.

```
var variable = "a", i, len;
alert(variable);
```

What does the first row do? All I can see it doing is assigning `"a"` to variable. But what happens with `i` and `len`?

Comment: You can find your answer here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 3):

Nothing apart from being declared as local variables.

```
var variable = "a", i, len;
```

is equivalent to

```
var variable = "a";
var i;
var len;
```

`var` declares a variable local to the current function scope.

Comment: Isn't it a little weird that they're declared on the right side of the equal sign? `var variable, i, len = "a"`would make more sense.

Comment: Yeah but `variable` and `i` would be undefined and `len` set to `"a"` instead

Comment: Basically scope doesn't matter here. This can happen globally and locally.

Comment: @Sandi equal sign is followed by a comma(`,`) that signifies the termination of previous statement and next variable definition will start

Comment: @phuzi your latest edit made your answer very similar to [@URE..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927832/%ea%9c%b1%e1%b4%9c%ca%80%e1%b4%87%ea%9c%b1%ca%9c-%e1%b4%80%e1%b4%9b%e1%b4%9b%e1%b4%80)'s answer. Please try not to duplicate content

Answer (score 3):

```
var variable = "a", i, len;
```

typically equates to

```
var variable = "a"; // declared and assigned the value "a"
var i;  // just declared
var len; // just declared
```

First is just declaring multiple variables in same line.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `var variable = "a", i, len;` two thins happen: variable declarations and variable initialisation. It's equivalent to

```
var variable = "a"
var i
var len
```

Where variable `variable` is declared and initialized with the value `"a"`. And variables `i` and `len` are only declared but not initialized. Variables that haven't been initialized get a value `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax

`var varname1 [= value1] [, varname2 [= value2] ... [, varnameN [= valueN]]];`

So basically its just a declaration, you can initialize each of them if you want.
Ref- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0):

we can declare any number of variables with single **var** keyword.If you don't assign any value the default value will be **undefined** .